# Amasty Abandoned Cart Email give subtotal without VAT

Tags: magento2, subtotal, amasty

I am using amasty Abandoned cart module. After one day we sent the 10% discount coupons for abadonded cart. But if product has a VAT , Subtotal deducted the vat price and calculate the 10% discount. Actual price should be subtotal calculate with VAT.

How to fix this issue.

[image]

Product price in **10.25**
Subtotal calculate to reduce the VAT and second value calculate 10% of the subtotal

Answer (score 0):

Please change the excludeTax to includeTax in the template content tab - https://screens.amasty.com/Screenshot2021-02-04_11.15.38.jpg

Additionally, please check your Magento settings - https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/tax/display-settings.html

Should you have any additional questions or request, feel free to contact Amasty support team via support@amasty.com

Thank you